# multiple comment refactoring in antlr4

Tags: antlr4

The book gives an example of comment rewriting (for refactoring an old code).

```
public void exitVarDecl(..) { // lexmagic/ShiftVarComments.java
    Token semi = ctx.getStop();
    int i = semi.getTokenIndex();
    List<Token> cmtChannel =
    tokens.getHiddenTokensToRight(i, CymbolLexer.COMMENTS);
    if ( cmtChannel!=null ) {
        Token cmt = cmtChannel.get(0);
        if ( cmt!=null ) {
            String txt = cmt.getText().substring(2);
            String newCmt = "/* " + txt.trim() + " */\n";
            rewriter.insertBefore(ctx.start, newCmt);
            rewriter.replace(cmt, "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately old code is never so easy. Often people put code in between a statement, instead of only at the end, eg:

```
// here is a simple array initialization
int index[2] = {  // list of parameter indices
   1,             // index for PARAM_A
   4              // index for PARAM_D
};                // finally terminating
```

The book code will only print the last comment. How to modify this code, so that ALL comments SINCE the previous print will be handled now?

Comment: `cmtChannel.get(0)` gets you only first comment - try to iterate through all possible values. If this doesn't work, you could iterate through declaration and fetch "first comment" at each literal.

Comment: You don't get any errors with this input? Assuming you are referring to Cymbol.g4 and it's unaltered.

Answer (score 0):

The last comment is the only comment to the right of your varDecl.  Your varDecl isn't complete until "};".  The other comments your looking for are scattered amongst (more like between) the parse tree nodes of your VarDecl AST.  To gather all of them, you'd need to hunt them all down.

Take a look at

public List getTokens(int start, int stop, Set types)

In BufferedTokenStream (superclass of CommonTokenStream).  In your exitVarDecl method, you can use ctx.getStart() and ctx.getStop() to get your 1st two parameters and then pass in a set containing CymbolLexer.COMMENTS.  That should give you all of the comments *inside* your varDecl (and you already have the code to grab the first comment outside.